# Unable to retrieve any child terms using get_terms

Tags: terms

For some reason I'm not able to retrieve any child terms for the `carabana_cat` taxonomy. Here's what I've done so far:

```
$custom_terms = get_terms( 'carabana_Cat', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'orderly' => 'description', 'child_of' => 28) );
```

What am I doing wrong here? There are lots of child terms for `id=28` which aren't showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try relying on the new WP_Term_Query() class, here's an example per your code:

```
 // WP_Term_Query arguments
$args = array( 
                'taxonomy'  => 'carabana_Cat', 
                'hide_empty' => false, 
                'orderby' => 'description', 
                'child_of' => 28) 
                );

// The Term Query
$term_query = new WP_Term_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomy names are case–sensitive:

```
d( taxonomy_exists( 'post_tag' ) ); // true
d( taxonomy_exists( 'post_Tag' ) ); // false
```

You seem to have mismatch between taxonomy name and your code.

PS also `orderly` reather than `orderby` typo.